# I think I may have DoS'ed a website accidentally

Tags: nmap, denial-of-service

I had recently started using the `nmap --script vuln` option and I did try it on my own local router IP, which then crashed and we had to restart (coincidence?).

Then today I wanted to try it again, and (probably against my best judgement) I did `nmap -Pn --script vuln <the website>` and while it was running I thought I should check the website. So I entered the url, and it said "This site can’t be reached  refused to connect. I also realized that I didn't check before if it was ever up.

1. did I Dos the site
2. will i be in legal trouble
3. any advice on what to do?

I then added www to the front of the website and it works now. I think I am fine.

Comment: Maybe, or maybe the web just block your ip because to many request. If you want to hack things, you better do ctf and then bug bounties. You can try this: https://www.hackthissite.org/
https://www.hackthebox.eu/
https://ctftime.org/ctfs/

Comment: `<the website.` - what website? Your router, like you talked about earlier? Or another website?

Answer (score 5):

You violated the golden rule of information security:

## NEVER ATTACK ANYTHING YOU HAVE NO PERMISSION TO ATTACK

Could it be that you crashed their server? Possibly. I don't have enough evidence to judge whether this is true or not. You claimed the website was reachable again later. Could be because the server was restarted; could be because it never crashed.

Could you be in legal trouble? Possibly, depending on your jurisdiction, and whether or not the company pursues charges against you.

If that is the case, get a lawyer. You acted recklessly, but not necessarily with the intent to cause damage. It may help.

As for the future: **Don't attack things that aren't yours, or things you don't have permission to attack. EVER!**